# What is the difference between a mock and a test double?

Tags: unit-testing, tdd, mocking

I was reading an article [here](https://blog.8thlight.com/uncle-bob/2014/05/14/TheLittleMocker.html) on Mocks. I would like to conclude to make my understanding more clear.

Anything that can be placed in place of a real object while testing is called a **Test Double**.

Depending on the testing need a Test Double can be categorized as follows:

- You need a placeholder object needed just for compiling / running a class then, create a **Dummy**.
- You want to test some part of the system in isolation which depends on some already tested system then, create a **Stub** which behaves as per your assumption.
- You want to make sure a function is called with some required argument then, you need a **Spy**.
- You need a **Fakes** when you want a **Stub** which behaves differently  depending on the use case.

#### What is a Mock then?

The above blog summarizes it as **any of the above family member of test double with assertion included is called a Mock**.

Example

```
public class AcceptingAuthorizerVerificationMock implements Authorizer {
  public boolean authorizeWasCalled = false;

  public Boolean authorize(String username, String password) {
    authorizeWasCalled = true;
    return true;
  }

  public boolean verify() {
    return authorizedWasCalled;
  }
}
```

But, **I am still confused about the assertion part because we already do assertions in our unit tests**.

Comment: You made perfect sense, but lost me at the last sentence. You could state your question more clearly?

Comment: @JDT edited question hope it makes more sense now.

Comment: @vivek What is it exactly you don't understand ? Uncle Bob's article is pretty clear on the subject

Comment: @guillaume31 first of all, I am asked to change my question for n number of iteration and when the question becomes trivial then I am asked what I didn't get. Very hilarious indeed!

Comment: I agree the question is trivial, in fact so trivial that you already answered it yourself : `Any of the above family member of test double with assertion included is called a Mock`. Pretty precise definition here. This is why we don't get what you don't understand...

Comment: The mock is aware of how to verify things, unlike all other types of doubles. The test calls the mock's `Verify()` method in its Assert part. That's really all there is to it.

Comment: @guillaume31 please check if you can see my original question before two edits. I think I was more clear there. Otherwise I can ask again. Thanks!

Comment: The question is well formulated with enough reading to give a proper background. It should be mandatory to give a proper reason before down voting because someone has invested a fair amount of time in it.

Answer (score 2):

Moving the assertion details from the test to the mock is all about *abstraction*.

It might not show in very simple tests like these, but sometimes you must verify complex things that happened - how many times was a method called ? Did the arguments passed match a given pattern ? This can require complex stuff behind the scenes.

Moving the details of analyzing what happened from the test to the mock allows the unit test to stay at a high language level and not pollute it with technical low level mock specifics.

[Edit]

You don't move the **act of asserting** to the mock. You move operational low-level assertion **details**.

Comment: I think my question is very clear now. The post title is very clear. I think its becoming a cult here to down vote some question requiring a little bit of thought process even the down voter isn't clear on how to answer, just copy pasting blog post in the question see answer by @BЈовић, its pathetic.

Comment: But... did I finally answer it or not ?

Comment: @vivek The reason some people (including me) are having difficulty understanding your question is that you seem to answer it ("Any of the above family member of test double with assertion included is called a Mock.") before you ask it.

Comment: @guillaume31 you answered it but you also down voted my question above seems contradictory :)

Comment: I didn't downvote it but voted for closing it, at a time when I was unaware that the original unedited version of the Q was much clearer. As others have pointed out, the second version of the Q was absurd IMO. You should edit a Q to make it *more* specific, not less.

Comment: @BenAaronson now I have made it much clear. Hopefully it makes much sense now.

Comment: @vivek Yes, it does. I've voted to reopen

Comment: can you please post a small example to get a better understanding of what you want to say.